# ASP.net checkboxlist not getting checked values

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkboxlist

I've checked all the answers but my problem seems different - i have two sets of checkbox list. On startup, i disable all checkboxes from the second set.

```
rotected void exchList_OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < exchList.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        exchList.Items[i].Attributes.Add("onclick", "gridCallback();");
        exchList.Items[i].Enabled = false;
    }//end for
}//end exchList_OnDataBound()
```

Checking a box in the first set enables boxes in another.  This is done via jquery.

```
$('#<%= exchList.ClientID %> input:checkbox').each(function() {
            $label = $(this).parent().children("label").text();
            i = 0;
            while(i < $jsonData.xxx.length)
            {
                if ($(this).attr('disabled'))
            {
                $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
            $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
                }//end if
            else
            {
                $(this).removeAttr('checked');
                $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }//end else
                i++;
            }//end while
    });
```

While the boxes to become checked, during the callback it is not detected.

```
protected void productGrid_OnCustomCallback(object sender,
                        DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewCustomCallbackEventArgs e)
{
    String markets = "", exchs = "";
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < marketList.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (marketList.Items[i].Selected)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(marketList.Items[i].Text);
    }//end for

    for (i = 0; i < exchList.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exchList.Items[i].Text + " " + exchList.Items[i].Enabled);
    }//end for
}//end productGrid_OnCustomCallback()
```

They are always not checked even when the checkboxes are clearly checked. Looking at firebug shows that because i disabled and enabled the list items, the checkboxes are encapsulated by a DIV, and this might be causing the issue. I tested it without the disable / enable, and the HTML had no DIV surrounding the checkboxes, and now it works properly. How do i get the checkbox checked value inside the DIV from the listitem?

Answer (score 1):

if I remember correctly, it's some sort of bug of the ASP.net controls that if a checkbox is disabled on page load, it always returns as unchecked, even if you enabled it and checked it on client side.
A workaround for this would be to send the checkboxes enabled from the server side, and disable them, if necessary, on loading on the client side.

IMHO, a prefferable solution would be, of course, to not use ASP.net controls at all, as I find them overly complex and overweight. but hey- that's just me...

Comment: but how else can i generate a checkbox list without using asp.net checkboxlist? i dun wanna use javascript ...

Comment: well, if you don't want to use client-side code to generate controls on client side, then... yeah, you're pretty much stuck with server side controls :). Personally I use a lot of javascript (actually- jQuery) and it has many controls which are much simpler, easier to use, and efficient, then asp.net ones. i'd recommend you give it a chance...

Answer (score -1):

try these codes I use using checkboxlist. it uses 2 pages. NO jscript code.. hope this helps.
1st page cs code.

```
Session["checkedarray"] = new string[] { "1.0", "2.0", "3.0" };
            {
                {
                    string[] checkedlist = new string[17];
                    int a = 0;

                    for (int i = 0; i <= 16; i++)
                    {
                        if (cblist1.Items[i].Selected == true)
                        {
                            checkedlist[a] = cbllist1.Items[i].ToString();
                            a = a + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    Session["checkedarray"] = checkedlist;
                    Session["numofchecked"] = a;
                    Response.Redirect("ReportPage2.aspx");
                }
            }
```

2nd page cs code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] arr = (string[])Session["checkedarray"];

    for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(Session["numofchecked"].ToString()); i++)
    {
        ColcbList2.Items.Add(arr[i].ToString());
    }
}
```